# AngularJS move scrollbar on keydown

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am making an autocomplete using angularJS. I am having an issue with the scrollbar. As you can see in [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fucke.gif), the scrollbar stays still when I am pressing arrow down/up. As I am pressing the arrow down key, how do I move the scrollbar with the highlighted option?

Here is my css code:

```
input {
  width: 300px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 306px;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid grey;  
}
.countries {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.countryIndex {
  background-color: #B2D7FE;
}
```

Try this [codepen](https://codepen.io/dhrubomoy/pen/LywEgG)

Comment: Try doing `overflow-y: scroll` instead of `auto`

Comment: @Baruch It didn't work. Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript to scroll. When the item that's selected with your `keydown` event is below `container.scrollHeight`, you need to scroll to it.

```
container.scrollTop = (item_index + 1) * item_height
```

Where

`item_index` = index of the item in the list.

`item_height` = height of each item in your dropdown.

`container` = countries DOM `$('.countries')`

Comment: `container.scrollHeight` will go all the way down, he only needs `(item_index + 1) * item_height`

Answer (score 1):

> **DataList**: you can use **HTML5** to handle your question, and you no need to make it yourself! it's already exist so use it.
>
> Sample on: [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp)
>
> **OR** some directives works with **datalist** too, you can use them too [angular-auto-complete](https://github.com/maherAshori/angular-auto-complete)

```html
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Not all browsers support this input. http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist